# How do I get this $g(x)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y′(x) + y(x)g′(x) = g(x)g′(x), y(0) = 0, x ∈ R$, where $f′(x)$ denotes $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$
 and $g(x)$ is a given non constant
differentiable function on R with $g(0) = g(2) = 0$. Then the value of $y(2)$ is ?

I'm having trouble in finding a concrete $g(x)$ Any help will be aprreciated

Comment: Just wondering, should it be $y'(x)g(x)$ instead of just $y'(x)$?

Comment: uhh, it's not so. sorry @CheeHan

Comment: Multiply both sides by $e^{g(x)}$ and integrate.

Comment: I thought about doing exactly what @ProfessorVector suggested, which is using integrating factor, but that the RHS now becomes $e^{g(x)}g(x)g'(x)$ and that scares me away. Now that I think of it, it might work out. Because observe that $e^{g(x)}g(x)g'(x) = g(x)\frac{d}{dx}(e^{g(x)})$ so you could actually do integration by parts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always like to think of these type of ODEs in terms of the product rule. Multiplying both sides by $e^{g(x)}$
yields (using the chain rule)
$$ \left(e^{g(x)}y(x)\right)'=e^{g(x)}y'(x)+y(x)e^{g(x)}g'(x)=e^{g(x)}g'(x)g(x)=\left(e^{g(x)}\right)' g(x).$$ Integrating from 0 to 2 and using integration by parts implies
$$y(2)=[e^{g(x)}y(x)]_0^2=\int_0^2 \left(e^{g(x)}y(x)\right)' dx=\int_0^2 \left(e^{g(x)}\right)' g(x) dx=[e^{g(x)}g(x)]_0^2-\int_0^2 e^{g(x)}g'(x)dx=-[e^{g(x)}]_0^2=-(1-1)=0.$$

Comment: $[e^{g(x)}y(x)]_0^2$ is $y(2)  - y(0)$. How do you find $y(0)$?

Comment: $y(0)=0$ is given.

Answer (score 0):

HINT :

Let $y=g+f \quad\to\quad f'+fg'=0\quad \text{linear ODE}\quad\to\quad f=c\:e^{-g}$